# Where is the char struct -​- operator defined in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

When I look at the documentation for the .NET Char Struct (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char), I can see the usual properties, methods, etc., as for any other Type defined in the .NET Framework.

I know that the char struct has a `--` operator defined for it as I can do the following:

```
char current = 'b';
current--;   // current now holds the value a.
```

When looking at the Microsoft documentation I would expect to see an operator overloading definition which would look something like :

```
public static Char operator --(char character)
{
}
```

The problem is I don't see anything like that neither it is said which operator is overloaded for the type. For the char Type example, char has an operator overload for -- but not for - and I think it would be good to know where all the overloaded operators are documented rather than do trials and errors.

So my questions are: How can one know which operator is defined for which type? Is it somewhere else in the .NET API documentation that I have missed?

Comment: "I know that the char struct has a -- Operator defined for it as I can do the following:"  Yeah, `char` is actually implemented as an unsigned number type.  It's been that way since C.

Comment: More specifically, from the documentation for `System.Char`: "The value of a Char object is its 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value."

Comment: I think you've found a hole in the C# documentation, because the decrement operator mentions only integral and floating point types (Note: a Char is _not_ converted to an Int16 by the decrement.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#decrement-operator---

Comment: Hi, @Powerlord thanks for your comment but I believe it might be inaccurate. You can indeed use the + or - operators on chars but in these case the char is implicitly casted to an int and so it uses the int Type + or - operators. For -- or ++, there are operators defined for the char type itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is described in the [C# Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction).
The [Integral Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#integral-types) topic lists the char type as being one of the integral types.

> The char type represents unsigned 16-bit integers with values between
>   0 and 65535. The set of possible values for the char type corresponds
>   to the Unicode character set. Although char has the same
>   representation as ushort, not all operations permitted on one type are
>   permitted on the other.

Regarding the operators you need to look at the [Prefix increment and decrement operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#prefix-increment-and-decrement-operators) topic in he C# language specification.

> Predefined ++ and -- operators exist for the following types: sbyte,
>   byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double,
>   decimal, and any enum type.

Comment: The problem is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#feedback) in the current .NET online docs - the char types has been left out, apparently accidentally. I've filed an issue.

Comment: Hi @AlesD, thanks for the answer. So these operators are defined at the language level, not the .Net Framework level isn't it ? I was confused with that as it is possible to overload operators on custom .Net Types liked explained here : [Operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Comment: Yes they are at the language level. As it says in the Operator Overloading topic you linked only a user-defined type can override predefined operators.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!